# Manually trigger a wp_schedule_event item?

Tags: wp-cron

I have successfully added an event via `wp_schedule_event` and I'd like to trigger it manually without disrupting the existing schedule.

Is there a way to tell WP to execute an event immediately without the cha-cha where I have to swap values in-and-out to get the event to fire *and* save/restore the existing (pre-manual call) timing on the event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just to [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)($hook) of your cronned event?

Comment: Where in the page execution would this be done? To run like a normal scheduled event, it would need the environment loaded up to the appropriate level.

Comment: Why not call the function directly: my_event_function();? do_action() did not work for me. So I just ran my event like that, adding the function call at the bottom of functions.php ...